# body missing when scraping with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to scrape this site but a bunch of elements are missing.

The response I am looking for looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://dramacool.so/favicon.png">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="" />

    <title>Watch full episode of True Beauty (2020) | Korean Drama | Dramacool</title>

    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="description" content="Watch full episode of True Beauty (2020) Korean drama | Dramacool">
    <meta name="keywords"
        content="True Beauty (2020), Watch True Beauty (2020) English Sub, True Beauty (2020) | Dramacool">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://cdn.videokvid.com/cover/true-beauty-2020.png" />

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="dramacool9" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Watch full episode of True Beauty (2020) | Korean Drama | Dramacool" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Watch full episode of True Beauty (2020) Korean drama | Dramacool">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://dramacool.so/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.videokvid.com/cover/true-beauty-2020.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cdn.videokvid.com/cover/true-beauty-2020.png" />

    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="Watch full episode of True Beauty (2020) | Korean Drama | Dramacool" />
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="Watch full episode of True Beauty (2020) Korean drama | Dramacool" />

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="5fe7040f1df5e">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_58x58.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_120x120.png" sizes="120x120" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_87x87.png" sizes="87x87" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_80x80.png" sizes="80x80" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_60x60.png" sizes="60x60" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_58x58.png" sizes="58x58" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dramacool.so/images/icon_16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://dramacool.so/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://dramacool.so/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dramacool.so/css/font-awesome.min.css?v=4.3" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dramacool.so/css/main.css?v=4.3" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dramacool.so/plugins/slick/slick.css?v=4.3" />

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var api_anclytic = 'https://dramacool.so/anclytic.html';
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <header>

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="https://dramacool.so" class="ads-evt">
                    <img src="https://dramacool.so/images/logo.jpg" alt="Dramacool" title="Dramacool" />    </a>
                    <div class="res_mobi menu_m">
                        <div class="left"><a href="#"
                                class="up-down menu_mobile"><img src="/images/mobi/up_down.png" alt="up-dow"></a></div>
                        <div class="right"><a
                                href="https://dramacool.so"><img src="/images/mobi/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <form class="search" action="/search">
                        <select name="type" id="search-type">
        <option value="movies">Movies</option>
        <option value="stars">Stars</option>
      </select>
                        <input type="text" id="search-key" name="keyword" placeholder="Search">
                        <button><img src="https://dramacool.so/images/button-search.png" alt="button search" /></button>
                    </form>
            </div>

            <nav class="menu_top">
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://dramacool.so"
                            title="Home"><img src="https://dramacool.so/images/home.png" alt="Home" title="Home" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/drama-list" title="Drama List">Drama List</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li><a href="/category/korean-drama" title="Korean Drama">Korean Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/japanese-drama" title="Japanese Drama">Japanese Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/taiwanese-drama" title="Taiwanese Drama">Taiwanese Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/hong-kong-drama" title="Hong Kong Drama">Hong Kong Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/chinese-drama" title="Chinese Drama">Chinese Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/american-drama" title="American Drama">American Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/other-asia-drama" title="Other Asia Drama">Other Asia Drama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/thailand-drama" title="Thailand Drama">Thailand Drama</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drama Movie</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li><a href="/category/korean-movies" title="Korean Movies">Korean Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/japanese-movies" title="Japanese Movies">Japanese Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/taiwanese-movies" title="Taiwanese Movies">Taiwanese Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/hong-kong-movies" title="Hong Kong Movies">Hong Kong Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/chinese-movies" title="Chinese Movies">Chinese Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/american-movies" title="American Movies">American Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/category/other-asia-movies" title="Other Asia Movies">Other Asia Movies</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/category/thailand-movies" title="Thailand Movies">Thailand Movies</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/kshow" title="KShow">KShow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/most-popular-drama" title="Popular Drama">Popular Drama</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/list-star.html" title="Popular Star">Popular Star</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/calendar" title="Drama Calendar">Drama Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://dramacool.info/user/request" target="_blank" title="Request Drama">Request
                            Drama</a></li>
                    <li class="user">
                        <a href="/login.html" title="login Dramacool">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-left">

                <div class="ads_place"></div>
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="details">
                        <div class="img">
                            <img src="https://cdn.videokvid.com/cover/true-beauty-2020.png" alt="True Beauty (2020)" />      </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                <h1>True Beauty (2020)</h1>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="follow">Follow</span>
                                </div>
                                <p class="other_name"><span>Other name: </span>


                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title="여신강림 ">여신강림 </a>
                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title=" 여신강림 "> 여신강림 </a>
                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title=" Yeoshingangrim "> Yeoshingangrim
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title=" Yeoshinkangrim "> Yeoshinkangrim
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title=" Yeosingangnim "> Yeosingangnim </a>
                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title=" The Secret of Angel "> The Secret
                                        of Angel </a>
                                    <a href="/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020" title=" Goddess Advent"> Goddess Advent</a>
                        <ul class="tab">
                            <li data-tab="left-tab-1" class="selected">View more video</li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class="show-all">Show all episodes</span>

                        <div class="block tab-container">
                            <div class="tab-content left-tab-1 selected">
                                <ul class="list-episode-item-2 all-episode">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/true-beauty-2020-episode-6.html" class="img">
                                            <span class="type SUB">SUB</span>
                                            <h3 class="title"
                                                onclick="window.location = '/true-beauty-2020-episode-6.html'">True
                                                Beauty (2020) Episode 6</h3>
                                            <span class="time">1 day ago</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/true-beauty-2020-episode-5.html" class="img">
                                            <span class="type SUB">SUB</span>
                                            <h3 class="title"
                                                onclick="window.location = '/true-beauty-2020-episode-5.html'">True
                                                Beauty (2020) Episode 5</h3>
                                            <span class="time">2 days ago</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/true-beauty-2020-episode-4.html" class="img">
                                            <span class="type SUB">SUB</span>
                                            <h3 class="title"
                                                onclick="window.location = '/true-beauty-2020-episode-4.html'">True
                                                Beauty (2020) Episode 4</h3>
                                            <span class="time">2020-12-17 11:39:48</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/true-beauty-2020-episode-3.html" class="img">
                                            <span class="type SUB">SUB</span>
                                            <h3 class="title"
                                                onclick="window.location = '/true-beauty-2020-episode-3.html'">True
                                                Beauty (2020) Episode 3</h3>
                                            <span class="time">2020-12-16 12:50:35</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/true-beauty-2020-episode-2.html" class="img">
                                            <span class="type SUB">SUB</span>
                                            <h3 class="title"
                                                onclick="window.location = '/true-beauty-2020-episode-2.html'">True
                                                Beauty (2020) Episode 2</h3>
                                            <span class="time">2020-12-10 12:44:28</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/true-beauty-2020-episode-1.html" class="img">
                                            <span class="type SUB">SUB</span>
                                            <h3 class="title"
                                                onclick="window.location = '/true-beauty-2020-episode-1.html'">True
                                                Beauty (2020) Episode 1</h3>
                                            <span class="time">2020-12-09 13:21:13</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-popup">
                        <h2>Login to Drama Cool</h2>
                        <a href="/login-google.html" class="btn-google">
                            <span><img src="https://dramacool.so/images/google.png" alt="google" /></span> Log in with
                            Google
                        </a>

                        <form method='post' action='/login.html'><input type='hidden' name='_csrf' value='5fe7040f1df5e' >
                            <input type='email' name='email'  placeholder='Email'  value=''>
                            <input type='password' name='password'  placeholder='Password' >
                            <input type='checkbox' name='remember'  value='1'> Remember me

                            <hr>

                            <a class="link-forget" href="/forget.html" title="Forgot password">Forgot password?</a>

                            <a class="link-signup" href="/register.html" title="Sign up">Sign up</a>

                            <button type='submit' >Sign in</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="content-right">
                    <div class="block fanpage">
                        <div>
                            <img src="https://dramacool.so/images/ic-new.svg" alt="Follow us on News" title="Follow us on News" />
                            <div><a href="https://dramacool.info/drama-news" target="_blank">Follow us on News</a></div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="https://dramacool.so/images/ic-upcoming.svg" alt="Follow us on Upcoming" title="Follow us on Upcoming" />
                            <div><a href="https://dramacool.info/upcoming-drama.html" target="_blank">Follow us on
                                    Upcoming</a></div>
            <footer>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/privacy" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/list-genres.html" title="Genres">Genres</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/disclaimer" title="Disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact-us" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button class="btn-btt"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> TOP</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="mask"></div>
        <div id="off_light"></div>
        <div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:calc(50% - 650px);"></div>
        <div style="position:fixed;top:0;right:calc(50% - 485px);display:none;"></div>
        <!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-101187474-5"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-101187474-5');
        </script>




        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/js/jquery.min.js?v=4.3"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/js/jquery-ui.min.js?v=4.3"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/plugins/lazyload/lazyload.min.js?v=4.3"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/js/main.js?v=4.3"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/js/mobi.js?v=4.3"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/js/detectmobilebrowser.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).on('load', function () {
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1203625996334867";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        });


        $("#search-key").autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            appendTo: '.form',
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/search',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        keyword: request.term,
                        type: $("#search-type").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: '',
                results: function () {
                }
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                url = ui.item.url;
                window.location = url;
            }
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li><a>")
                    .append("<img src='https://cdn.videokvid.com/" + item.cover + "' /><div class='info'><div>" + item.name + "</div><div>" + item.status + "</div></div><div class='clearfix'></div></a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/plugins/slick/slick.min.js?v=4.3"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dramacool.so/js/bookmark.js?v=4.3"></script>

        <script>
            var disqus_shortname = "dramacool";
    var disqus_url = "http://drama9.io/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020";
    $(window).on('load', function () {
      (function () {
        var dsq = document.createElement("script");
        dsq.type = "text/javascript";
        dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = "//" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js";
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(dsq);

        var dsqcount = document.createElement("script");
        dsqcount.type = "text/javascript";
        dsqcount.async = true;
        dsqcount.src = "//" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/count.js?";
        dsqcount.id = 'dsq-count-scr', (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(dsqcount);
      })();
    });

    $('.slider-star').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
    });
    $('.mask').click(function () {
      $('.login-popup').fadeOut();
    });
    var e_follow = '.follow';
            $(e_follow).click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(".mask").fadeIn();
            $('.login-popup').fadeIn();  
        });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .login-popup {
                position: fixed;
                background: rgba(236, 235, 238, 0.9);
                max-width: 300px;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 16;
                padding: 22px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: 50px;
                margin: auto;
                display: none;
                color: #000
            }

            .login-popup hr {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                visibility: hidden
            }

            .login-popup h2 {
                text-align: center;
                color: #3EC2CF;
                font-size: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 10px
            }

            .login-popup .btn-facebook,
            .login-popup .btn-google {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 7px 0;
                position: relative;
                color: #FFF;
                font-size: 14px
            }

            .login-popup .btn-facebook:hover,
            .login-popup .btn-google:hover {
                color: #FFF
            }

            .login-popup .btn-facebook {
                background: #3b5998
            }

            .login-popup .btn-google {
                background: #dd4b39
            }

            .login-popup .btn-facebook span,
            .login-popup .btn-google span {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 40px;
                padding: 10px 0;
                text-align: center;
                margin-right: 10px
            }

            .login-popup .btn-facebook img,
            .login-popup .btn-google img {
                height: 17px
            }

            .login-popup .btn-facebook span {
                background-color: #2f477a
            }

            .login-popup .btn-google span {
                background-color: #b13c2e
            }

            .login-popup input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
                width: 100%;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                appearance: none;
                border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
                height: 40px;
                margin: 7px 0;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box
            }

            .login-popup .link-forget {
                float: right;
                color: #000
            }

            .login-popup .link-signup {
                float: left;
                color: #000
            }

            .login-popup button {
                margin-top: 7px;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                background: #3EC2CF;
                color: #fff;
                border: none;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0;
                -webkit-appearance: none
            }

            .follow {
                background-color: #FDB813;
                padding: 5px 15px;
                display: inline-block;
                cursor: pointer;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #fff !important;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            .follow.active {
                background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 93.3%);
                color: #999 !important;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            (function(d,z,s,c){s.src='//'+d+'/400/'+z;s.onerror=s.onload=E;function E(){c&&c();c=null}try{(document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(s)}catch(e){E()}})('in-page-push.com',3785521,document.createElement('script'),_tktctaws)
        </script>
        <div
            style='    z-index:99999;position: fixed;bottom: 0;text-align: center;width: 100%; left: 0;padding: 10px;background: #3ec2cf;color: white;'>
            We moved to <a style='color:#000 !important;font-weight: bold !important;' title='Dramacool'
                href='https://dramacool.so'>Dramacool.so</a>, please bookmark new link. Thank you!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

But what actually returns from axios is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html lang="en-US"\n
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"\n      itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">\n
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">\n    
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>\n
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">\n\n
            <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">\n\n
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://dramacool.so/favicon.png">\n
                    <meta name="google-site-verificatio…try{(document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(s)}catch(e){E()}})('in-page-push.com',3785521,document.createElement('script'),_tktctaws)
                    </script>\n
                    <div style='    z-index:99999;position: fixed;bottom: 0;text-align: center;width: 100%; left: 0;padding: 10px;background: #3ec2cf;color: white;'>We moved to 
                        <a style='color:#000 !important;font-weight: bold !important;' title='Dramacool' href='https://dramacool.so'>Dramacool.so</a>, please bookmark new link. Thank you!
                    </div>
                </body>\n
            </html>
```

What's confusing is that Postman works just fine but I've tried it with axios and cloudscraper (thinking it might've been a cloudflare issue.) but no dice.

here is my code for scraping:

```
let config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://dramacool.so/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020',
    headers: { 
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36', 
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9', 
      'Cookie': '__cfduid=db54578ab04402295c17b4ea9fb86314a1608975375; dramacool=2o94nvtl4tfkrph5p80j0ii5o2'
    }
  };

const request = await axios(config);
    //const request = await axios.default.get("https://dramacool.so/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020")
    //let test = await cloudscraper.get("https://dramacool.so/drama-detail/true-beauty-2020");
    const resp = await request.data;
    

    let { document } = new JSDOM(resp).window;
//From here on the code would just fail because of incorrect response data.
```

UPDATE:

I just tried using http and request and both work, but Axios, cloudscraper, got, SuperAgent all fail... Perhaps an issue with promise-based methods? Any ideas?

Comment: Compare the headers (including implicit headers) you are sending with axios to the headers you are sending with postman. (And "remote debugging" in Q&A format is really difficult to do).

Comment: can you add the code you're using to scrape?

Comment: @dirkt In the updated code, you can see I tried code generated with postman. So they would have the same headers.

Comment: @sabotage They're up!

Answer (score 0):

So weird thing, `request-promises-native` works when paired with `cheerios`, but `Axios` does not. While I'd rather have something that isn't depreciated, this will have to suffice if nobody else is able to answer why they rest of the promise-based methods fail.